# Prove that $y^2+x^2+c^2x^2(1-x^2)=1$ is closed as a path.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, curves, implicit-function

How can I prove that the curve defined implicitly by $y^2+x^2+c^2x^2(1-x^2)=1$ and passes through the point (0,1) is closed as path when $c\in(0,1)$. Where closed means that for a parametrization $f(t):[0,1]\to \mathbf{R}^2$ of the curve, we have  $f(0)=f(1)$.

Comment: Show that for each $x$ there are at most two values of $y.$ Then since $y$ is a continuous function of $x,$ the curve must be closed. Otherwise, let $y=mx,$ with $m$ a parameter. Then show that the resulting equation $x^2(k-x^2)=1$ always has at most two real solutions.

Comment: Why the argument is not applicable to the curve $y^2-x^2=1$ which is not closed?

Comment: I have understood now that by "closed" you mean as a path, not topologically. Well in this case you are right, this is completely different. Let me think about it. (And you should edit your question, looking at the upvotes I received I am not the only one having understood it like I did)

Comment: @Almostnice If you are referring to me, then the first curve can be shown to stay in a bounded region of the plane. The second extends to infinity. (Actually, it is closed if you include the endpoints of the real line to get a completed $\mathrm R^2.$